# turboTable primeng input enterKey

Tags: html, input, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Using the incell editing for the primeng TurboTable, I am trying to execute a method by clicking on enter key. Here is the following code:

```
    <td pEditableColumn>
       <p-cellEditor>
      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.vin" (keyup.enter)="onKeyPress($event)">
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="output">
        {{rowData.vin}}
      </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
  </td>
```

The problem is that the method `onKeyPress` is not executed by clicking on the enterKey. So I've tried with `keypress` as following:

```
    <td pEditableColumn>
       <p-cellEditor>
      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.vin" (keypress)="onKeyPress($event)">
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="output">
        {{rowData.vin}}
      </ng-template>
    </p-cellEditor>
  </td>
```

And what I've noticed is that the method `onKeyPress` is executed by clicking on any button except the enter Key.

Answer (score 2):

I Tried to use `keydown` instead of `Keyup` and it works fine

```
<td pEditableColumn>
   <p-cellEditor>
     <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.vin" 
               (keydown.enter)="onKeyDown($event)">
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                {{rowData.vin}}
     </ng-template>
   </p-cellEditor>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think onEditComplete event catches the enter key press.
Check https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table under Events.

To call your function on enter key press you can do this:

```
<p-table ... (onEditComplete)="onEditComplete($event)">
...
<td [pEditableColumn]="rowData" pEditableColumnField="'vin'">

In your component:
onEditComplete(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```